# Spring Security 6.x what is the replacement for PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring-security

We have a custom PermissionEvaluator and it is no longer being called when we upgraded Spring boot to 3.x and also required that Spring Security be bumped to Spring Security 6.x

We used to do this

```
class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler()
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator)
    return expressionHandler
}
```

}

But that has been deprecated/removed but the documentation that I read does not show what the new way to do it is.

Sorry for this rant, but Spring Security always does this, they make new versions and change everything so that you have to re-write everything and it is so different that it never works.

Comment: The Spring Security documentation describes the [new way to configure a custom PermissionEvaluator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#servlet-replace-permissionevaluator-bean-with-methodsecurityexpression-handler).

Comment: Thanks Chin, I see they didn't put that in the 6.x documentation, It is in the previous versions.

Comment: In that link they have it as "static" but I need to use beans to inject into it and those aren't static.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
static MethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler(CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator) {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
    return expressionHandler;
}
```

Comment: This is just a copy paste from the link @Chin Huang posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided by DingHao and Chin Huang works for me.
If you look at the source code of Spring Security, they expose the setPermissionEvaluator method, if you do not set it, the default DenyAllPermissionEvaluator will be used.
Here is my code:

```
 @Autowired
 CustomPermissionEvaluator customPermissionEvaluator;

 @Bean
 MethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    var expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(customPermissionEvaluator);
    return expressionHandler;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, Chin's is the correct answer.